# how to assign to slice of slice in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a pandas dataframe *df* as shown.

```
   col1  col2
0   NaN     a
1     2     b
2   NaN     c
3   NaN     d
4     5     e
5     6     f
```

I want to find the first NaN value in col1 and assign a new value to it. I've tried both of the following methods but none of them works.

```
df.loc[df['col'].isna(), 'col1'][0] = 1

df.loc[df['col'].isna(), 'col1'].iloc[0] = 1
```

Both of them don't show any error or warning. But when I check the value of the original dataframe, it doesn't change.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) with `limit=1` parameter:

```
df['col1'].fillna(1, limit=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1 col2
0   1.0    a
1   2.0    b
2   NaN    c
3   NaN    d
4   5.0    e
5   6.0    f
```

Comment: This is a good idea! But what if I want to fill the second NaN? or just random indices I select, for example, from M'th to N'th [M:N]?

Comment: @theoxx For example `df.loc[df[df['col1'].isna()].index[2], 'col1'] = 1` will change row `3   1.0    d`